# How to bind a ComboBox to List<string> in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm trying to bind a ComboBox to `List<string>` Units. But it doesn't display anything. Here is the code I have put together so far.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Units}"/>

public partial class Statusbar
{

    public List<string> Units { get; set; }

    public Statusbar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Units = new List<string> {"KN-mm", "KN-cm", "KN-m"};

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set DataContext? You can set both in XAML(Window.DataContext property) / Code behind (this.DataContext property within constructor of Mainwindow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the source object of the binding. One way would be to set the control's `DataContext` property:

```
public Statusbar()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Units = new List<string> {"KN-mm", "KN-cm", "KN-m"};
    DataContext = this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Clemens, I had missed that.